# Samsung 700z Laptop Unusual Screen Flickering

Tags: bios, laptop

I received a laptop from a client yesterday reporting that the computer "constantly reboots". From what I can tell, the screen tends to turn on again/off again but displays nothing other than a black screen (no cursor, nothing) when flickered to on (for the second it remains on before going off again), but there is no indication the PC is rebooting as the hard drive remains spinning along with the system fans and LEDs do not flash as they commonly do when first booting the laptop. Another variation is that the BIOS screen will appear and display the Samsung logo when cold booted. This does not occur during the screen flickering at all.

Here are my troubleshooting steps:

1. Attempted a fresh install of Windows via USB. Windows installed without issue and laptop and screen stayed on throughout the process as normal. Upon first boot from hard drive, screen repeated the flickering behavior.
2. Removed/replaced hard drive with a trusted and operational drive. Installed Windows as I did in step 1 successfully. Upon first boot from hard drive, screen repeated flickering behavior.
3. Ran Hiren's Boot CD from USB and ran mini WinXP. PC remained stable and operable throughout the testing process for hours. Conducted thorough testing of components -- RAM, CPU, and, just to be thorough, the hard drive. All tests returned zero errors or any indication of hardware failure. PC remains completely operable if OS is run from USB.
4. Turned my attention to BIOS settings. Disabled EDB and any other unneeded BIOS features (went as barebones as disabling hyperthreading and power save mode for CPU, along with everything else I could possibly disable) and rebooted, again, to no avail as I experienced the flickering behavior upon reboot.
5. CMOS battery has been tested and is 100% operable. BIOS time is precisely accurate.

I was going to flash the BIOS, but as far as I can tell on the Samsung website, this can only be done from Windows.

Here's what I've gathered thus far from these tests:

1. It doesn't appear to be the hard drive. I've used several drives (including a brand new one) and verified using my own laptop that all drives are in perfect working condition.
2. The screen does not seem to be physically damaged, due to the fact that I can boot from any OS via USB and the screen will stay on for hours. Also notable to mention that the hard drive is completely accessible, responsive and usable in the USB OS environments.
3. All hardware has been tested and verified, and according to all tests, it appears as if all hardware is operating normally.

I'm guessing its the BIOS? I would never otherwise guess that but I'm at a loss as to what is constantly causing this thing to flicker as it does.

Comment: I've seen some problems with graphic cards that would handle absolutely fine on lower resolutions, but would cause flickering on higher resolutions. Not a real solution but perhaps an avenue to investigate?

Comment: You've clearly wasted too much time on this already.  If it's under warranty, return it and let Samsung deal with it.  If it's out of warranty, time to buy one that *is* in warranty.

Comment: I appreciate the response. Unfortunately I don't think it's the graphics card only because I cannot even coax an advanced startup menu beyond the BIOS, or anything else for that matter. Almost instantly, the computer starts flickering immediately after the BIOS loads to 100%.

Comment: I'd generally agree with you, Hopeless, but I was tasked with providing my boss with -- at best -- a fixed laptop or at least an explanation as to what is causing this behavior. Unfortunately at my job my boss generally doesn't accept "it's just not working" as a reasonable response to a client inquiry.

Comment: While it's powered on, pour some water into the GPU.  You'll be able to honestly diagnose the problem as a massive short circuit in the GPU to satisfy your boss, and move onto something more useful, to satisfy yourself.

Comment: Have you installed the latest driver for the video card? What happens if you load the Standard VGA Graphics Adapter driver?

Comment: @joeqwerty -- As mentioned I can't even get into an advanced startup options menu (which doesn't need the standard vga adapater to use to my knowledge). Literally less than a second after the BIOS loads, the screen starts flickering on-again, off-again by the second. I did install fresh copies of Windows and now Ubuntu with the same flickering results.

Comment: Gotcha. What does it do with an external monitor connected?

Comment: @fixer1234 -- I had the same feeling, but if my portable OS's have no problem functionality-wise with the display for hours on end, it would lead me to believe that the connectors are not the issue, unless you can suggest otherwise.

Comment: If the problem goes away when you boot from a USB drive (particularly a different OS), the difference could be in the video driver.  Try reloading or updating that.

Comment: The laptop itself only has an HDMI input, so I'll be limited to testing with a rather higher-end connection, but I will give that a whirl. As far as video drivers go, I imagine reinstalling the entire OS from scratch would render the driver update a moot point, but I've seen weirder things in the past so I'll give that a try as well.